# JNIEnv->GetMethodID leads a crash

Tags: java-native-interface, jvmti

```
jclass clazz_obj = jni_env->GetObjectClass(klazz);
    
jmethodID mid = jni_env->GetMethodID(clazz_obj, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

This is the stacktrace:

V  [libjvm.so+0x74e290]  JvmtiRawMonitor::is_valid()+0x0

C  [libVWave.so+0x73cd0]  JNIEnv_::GetMethodID(_jclass*, char const*, char const*)+0x3c

I want to get the full name of a class. However, jvmti doesn't have this API. I try to do this in MethodEntry CallBack to get the full name by JNI.

Comment: Was `clazz_obj` valid? Was there a pending exception when you called `GetMethodID()`? Don't write JNI code like this. You have to error- and exception-check *every JNI call.*

Comment: No API in JVMTI for [getting the class name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jvmti.html#GetClassSignature)?